# How to get rkhunter PORT_WHITELIST='* ...' to work on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, rkhunter

My /etc/rkhunter.conf.local contains this line:

```
PORT_WHITELIST='* TCP:7000'
```

If I run rkhunter -c it appears that the star is being shell expanded:

```
root@willow / # rkhunter -c
Invalid entry specified in PORT_WHITELIST configuration option: bin
Invalid entry specified in PORT_WHITELIST configuration option: boot
...
```

Does anyone know a way around this? I am using rkhunter 1.4.2-5 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like using the last `rkhunter` copies, you should update your conf from:

```
PORT_WHITELIST="/path/to/bin PROTO:PORT"
```

to:

```
PORT_PATH_WHITELIST="/path/to/bin"
PORT_WHITELIST="PROTO:PORT"
```

In your case:

```
PORT_PATH_WHITELIST="*" #or whatever bin binds to TCP:7000
PORT_WHITELIST="TCP:7000"
```